# Populating a select tag with a DB in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to generate a select tag with data from a mysql DB the form isn't in a regular view but it is in a partial view file so it appears in the whole site so I can't use a regular controller.

I'm getting the data from the DB from the BaseController and passig the data through a function, my code in the controller looks like this:

```
protected function setupLayout() {
    if (!is_null($this->layout)) {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
    View::composer('partials.footer', function ($view) {
        $languages = array('' => 'Choose Language Pair:') + Languages::lists('name', 'id');
        $view->with('languages', $languages);
    });
}
```

Then my blade on the select par looks like this:

```
{{ Form::select('sourceLang', $languages,  Input::old('sourceLang'), array('class' => 'field required')); }}
```

I'am quite new with Laravel and I came up with this code following a tutorial but it doesn't seem to work it throws the Undefined variable: languages error like the view isn't getting the data from the DB...

I'll appreciate any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the view composer before calling `View::make()`:

```
View::composer('partials.footer', function ($view) {
    $languages = array('' => 'Choose Language Pair:') + Languages::lists('name', 'id');
    $view->with('languages', $languages);
});
if (!is_null($this->layout)) {
    $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
}
```

Actually I wouldn't register the composer in `setupLayout()` at all. Instead I recommend you add a new file `app/composers.php` to store all your view composers. Then you need to include it somewhere. For example in `app/start/global.php` at the bottom:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Comment: And the view code (`{{ Form::select(...`) is inside the view `partials.footer`?

Comment: Can you add `dd('test')` inside the view composer function to check if it get's executed?